# How to remove element from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm new to nodejs and mongodb. My problem is I've a json of following type

```
{ 
 _id: 199,
 name: 'Rae Kohout',
 scores: [ 
     { type: 'exam', score: 82.11742562118049 },
     { type: 'quiz', score: 49.61295450928224 },
     { type: 'homework', score: 28.86823689842918 },
     { type: 'homework', score: 5.861613903793295 }
 ]
}
```

Here I want to compare score for the type 'homework' and remove the homework which has lowest score.To solve this I've written some code like

```
var low = '';
for(var i=0;i<doc.scores.length;i++)
{
 if(doc.scores[i].type == 'homework'){
   if(low == ''){
      low = doc.scores[i].score;
   }
   if( doc.scores[i].score > low ){
     console.log("index for lowest score is " + i);
     low = '';
   }
 }
}
```

Now I'm able to find the index for the lowest score, and want to removes values at that index. I tried to use Array.splice() method but that works on Array only. can anyone help me to solve it ?

Comment: What do you want the end result to be?  `scores` is an array, so you can use splice on it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `splice` like so:

```
doc.scores.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: +1 This is the proper way to remove an element from an array.

Comment: "When the splice method is called with two or more arguments start, deleteCount and (optionally) item1, item2, etc., the deleteCount elements of the array starting at array index start are replaced by the arguments item1, item2, etc. An Array object containing the deleted elements (if any) is returned. " - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12

Comment: What should I do if I want to move it to another json variable ??

Answer (score 2):

The **splice()** method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

if you want to Remove 1 element from index 3. try this

```
var myArray = ['angel', 'clown', 'drum', 'mandarin', 'sturgeon'];
var removed = myArray.splice(3, 1);

// removed is ["mandarin"]
// myArray is ["angel", "clown", "drum", "sturgeon"]
```